# A question on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $T$ be a linear operator on $V$.

Condition 1: there exists $0\neq v\in V$ such that $v, Tv,\ldots, T^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent. 
Condition 2: $ST=TS\iff S$ can be written as a polynomial in $T$.

Try to show condition 1 and condition 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Didn't get. What is $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 1) implies Condition 2) : Assume $T S = S T$ and write $S v = P(T)v$, such a thing is possible because the powers $T^jv$ are a base of $V$. Then for each $j$ you have $$ S T^j v = T^j S v = T^j P(T) v = P(T) T^j v$$
and so the linear map $S$ agree with the linear map $P(T)$ on all vectors of the base $T^j v$, $j=0,...,(n-1)$. Thus, $S = P(T)$. This shows one implication. The other one, namely, if $S = P(T)$ then $ST = TS$ is obvious.

To show that Condition 2) implies Condition 1) the only way I see is to use the so called rational normal form. That is to say, to follow the hint the  other user gave you. See for example : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html

Answer (score 3):

In fact condition 1 is equivalent to: the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ coincide, which in turn is equivalent to that the eigenvalues from each Jordan block of the canonical form of $T$ are distinct.

If $ST=TS$ is equivalent to $S$ expressible as a polynomial of $T$, then the eigenvalues from each Jordan block of the canonical form of $T$ are distinct. To see this, suppose for simplicity $T$ is already in its Jordan canonical form and contains two Jordan blocks $J_m(\lambda)$ and $J_n(\lambda)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $S$ contains $J_m(\mu)$ and $J_n(\nu)$ ($\mu\neq \nu$) as block submatrices in the same position as $J_m(\lambda)$ and $J_n(\lambda)$ in $T$. Obviously those block sub matrices commute but $S$ can never be polynomial of $T$ as the polynomial of $J_n(\lambda)$ and $J_m(\lambda)$ still has the same eigenvalue (being power of $\lambda$). Conversely, if the eigenvalues from each Jordan block of the canonical form of $T$ are distinct, then $ST=TS$ implies that $S$ can be simultaneously conjugated to the Jordan canonical form of the same shape as $T$, and thus $S$ can be written as a polynomial of $T$.

All in all, condition 1 and 2 are equivalent.

Comment: But $T$ does not necessarily have a Jordan normal form because the base field for vector space $V$ is not necessarily algebraically closed. I would suggest using the rational normal form, which does not need the field to be special.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $F$ denote the base field of $V$. Defining $X\cdot v:=Tv$ makes $V$ a $F[X]$-module. Note that $ST=Ts$ is equivalent to say $S$ is a $F[X]$-endomorphism, so condition 1 says that $V$ is a cyclic $F[X]$-module (that is, a singly generated $F[X]$-module), and condition 2 says that $\text{End}_{F[X]}(V)$ is exactly a quotient ring of $F[X]$.

Comment: I presuppose OP knows the basic ideas of module theory, especially the decomposition of a finitely generated module over a PID, which I think is necessary for solving this question.